# Running elpy-test on a file opened over ssh via tramp

Tags: python, tramp, elpy, virtualenv

I'm trying to run elpy's `C-c C-t` to do `elpy-test` on a python `test_x.py` file I have opened on a remote machine with TRAMP.

Some parameters:

- There is a python virtual env in the (remote machine's) directory, `~/myproject/env/default/`
- I want to run the tests relative to the (remote machine's) project root `~/myproject/`
- The PYTHONPATH is set to the root directory, which is  `~/myproject/`

Locally, I run `C-c C-t` and this works like so:

```
-*- mode: compilation; default-directory: "~/myproject/test/integration/data/mymod/" -*-
Compilation started at Thu May 13 13:56:38

py.test --log-level\=DEBUG /home/user/myproject/test/integration/data/mymod/mod2/test_x.py\:\:test_y
================================================================================ test session starts =================================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.7.3, pytest-5.4.3, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1 -- /env/default/bin/python
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /home/user/myproject, inifile: pytest.ini
plugins: asyncio-0.14.0, flask-1.1.0, forked-1.2.0, xdist-1.33.0, requests-mock-1.8.0, typeguard-2.7.0
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                                     

mod2/test_x.py::test_y SKIPPED                                                                                                    [100%]

============================================================================= slowest 10 test durations ==============================================================================
0.00s setup    test/integration/data/mymod/mod2/test_x.py::test_y
0.00s teardown test/integration/data/mymod/mod2/test_x.py::test_y
================================================================================= 1 skipped in 2.05s =================================================================================

Compilation finished at Thu May 13 13:56:41
```

This looks good.  This is exactly what I want to see.

However, when I remotely open the same file, and expect it to run on the remote machine via TRAMP, picking up the remote environment:

```
-*- mode: compilation; default-directory: #("/ssh:remote:/home/user/myproject/test/integration/data/mymod/" 1 4 (helm-ff-file t) 5 13 (helm-ff-file t)) -*-
Compilation started at Thu May 13 14:00:37

py.test --log-level\=DEBUG /ssh\:remote\:/home/user/myproject/test/integration/data/mymod/mod2/test_x.py\:\:test_y
/bin/sh: 2: py.test: not found

Compilation exited abnormally with code 127 at Thu May 13 14:00:37
```

Some things I notice:

- The default directory looks mostly correct AFAICT, but I'm not sure what the `#()` is doing.
- It's not clear to me why py.test is not found.
- I don't see elpy listing any of that other stuff, like cachedir or platform---is it not configured at all?
- Is there a variable I need to set either within emacs, orperhaps an environment variable, etc., so that when executed remotely, I can pick up the local environments?

Additionally, I have a `.dir-locals.el` in the root where I can set these as needed, if they are location-specific.

What can I change so I can run my tests with elpy over a tramp ssh session successfully?

Answer (score 1):

I have no knowledge about elpy and the like. However, some observations:

- py.test is not found because its location is not mentioned in the remote $PATH
- The call of py.test comes with a remote file name `/ssh\:remote\:/home/...`. This looks wrong.

I recommend to contact the author(s) of elpy whether it is prepared for remote activation.